# Now Playing Card

Tags: android, android-service, android-5.0-lollipop, android-tv

I need help about displaying the Now Playing Card in the Recommendations row. I read the post about it in the Android developers site, but that did not help me much.

I have a service that streams the MP3 data without problems. I added the following code, but there's no Now Playing Card...

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate called");

    mSession = new MediaSession(this, "MusicService");
    mSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCallback());
    mSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
            MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

    mSession.setActive(true);
}


private class MediaSessionCallback extends MediaSession.Callback {
}
```

**Edit:** Added code for meta-data:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate called");

    mSession = new MediaSession(this, "MusicService");
    mSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCallback());
    mSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
            MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);


    final MediaMetadata.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadata.Builder();

    String title = "Burak";

    metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_TITLE, title);
    metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_SUBTITLE,
            "Burak müzik");
    metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON_URI,
            "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/android-tv/Sample%20videos/Zeitgeist/Zeitgeist%202010_%20Year%20in%20Review/card.jpg");

    // And at minimum the title and artist for legacy support
    metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, title);
    metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "BKD Mobile");

    mSession.setMetadata(metadataBuilder.build());

    mSession.setActive(true);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say you need to specify the metadata for the current playing MP3 file via the [`Metadata.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/now-playing.html#metadata) class:

```
MediaMetadata.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadata.Builder();
metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_TITLE,
        "Title");
metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_SUBTITLE,
        "Subtitle");
metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON_URI,
        "Artwork");
mSession.setMetadata(metadataBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding that did not display the Now Playing card either. Could it be because I placed the code in the service instead of the fragment or the activity?

Comment: Not sure about this. Is your app requesting audio focus correctly? "Note that your app must request the audio focus, as described in Managing Audio Focus."

Comment: @burakk Did you manage to display the Now Playing card? Do you mind sharing if the audio focus was missing or if it was because of something else? That's going to be helpful for others as well.

Comment: I managed it to be displayed, but it is inconsistent. It is displayed only when coming back to the Home screen second time. It does not work on the first time. I will determine the cause and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late to help the OP, but in the event someone runs across this page, I wanted to share a possible answer.  You should ensure that you are calling mSession.setPlayBackState(state) at some point.  For instance, try doing something like this to start:

```
            mediaSession.setMetadata(builder.build());
        PlaybackState state = new PlaybackState.Builder()
                .setActions(
                        PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackState
                                .ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT | PlaybackState.ACTION_REWIND |
                                PlaybackState.ACTION_FAST_FORWARD)
                .setState(PlaybackState.STATE_NONE, 0, 1.0f)
                .build();
        mediaSession.setPlaybackState(state);
```

You'll need to adjust the actions based on your needs. My guess is that you are setting state later, which is why you notice it working when returning to the Home screen on the subsequent attempt.