# How to implement "Now Playing Card" for my Android TV App?

Tags: android-tv

I'm pretty sure I added all the code mentioned on the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/now-playing. I have it all spread it out, but here is on the `onCreate` to simplify:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tv)

        session = MediaSession(this, "MyAPP")
        session.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS or MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS)
        session.setCallback(object : MediaSession.Callback() {
            override fun onPause() {
                super.onPause()
                player?.playWhenReady = false
            }

            override fun onPlay() {
                super.onPlay()
                player?.playWhenReady = true
            }
        })

        session.isActive = true

        val metadataBuilder = MediaMetadata.Builder().apply {
            putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_TITLE, "Title")
            putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_SUBTITLE, "Some subtitle")
            putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))

            putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "Title again")
            putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "Artist")

        }
        session.setMetadata(metadataBuilder.build())
        val stateBuilder = PlaybackState.Builder().setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE) //just one to test
        session.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build())

        //volumeControlStream = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC

        //setupList()
    }
```

When I press home the sound keep playing, but no video and no Now Playing Card.

what am i missing?

I already look at this: [Now Playing Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945306/now-playing-card)
and this [Android Tv - Now playing card icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603038/android-tv-now-playing-card-icon)
and this [How to display Now Playing Card on Android TV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454894/how-to-display-now-playing-card-on-android-tv), but none of those questions/answers helped me.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find any solution? I don't have TV for testing, and it is not working in tv emulator.

Comment: @SwapnilChaudhari nope, I never found the solution.

Comment: I am also facing this issue
Is any update on this? @Julio_oa

Comment: any update about this issue?